# How is there no such target multi-user.target in --user context?

Tags: systemd

I read this paragraph in a mailing list and it's confusing me:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67471#c11

```
There is no such target "multi-user.target" in --user contexts.
Use default.target in [Install]'s WantedBy= instead.
```

I'm aware that targets are synchronization points during a system start-up. I can see all the targets using this command:

```
systemctl list-units --type target
```

I know my default.target from using this command:

```
systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

I'm aware that unit files placed in `/etc/systemd/user/` or `~/.config/systemd/user/` can be running using `systemctl --user ...` if the `systemd --user` daemon is running and the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is set.

I thought the point of the `[Install]` section was to configure what happens when I enable a unit.

How is there no such target in a multi-user.target in a --user context?
What does that mean?

Comment: Uh…don't you feel weird if it has a target called "multi-user" when it's user instance? Did you have any misunderstanding about systemd user instance?